# Eclipse does not recognize code changes

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

Just note that I am looking for possible solutions for more then couple of hours. I saw similar problems on Stack Overflow but this just not work.

Ok so I have created a Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse Kepler. Later I shared everything with my team mate. Problem arises when he is trying to change one of the classes. He changed private field to something else. But when he restart tomcat server republish code he got an exception that path to the file is invalid. But he changed that!!!

Eclipse still thinks that variable has an old value.

Any idea how to fix it? We restarted eclipse multiple times, restarted tomcat server.

Comment: Hard to help with such a vague description. path to file? what file? what variable? how do you build? how do you deploy?

Comment: `private File propertiesRuleFile = new File("C:/user1/bwcPropertyRules.xml");`

and he just changes that to:

`private File propertiesRuleFile = new File(
   "C:/user2/bwcPropertyRules.xml");`

StackTrace is showing old value for `propertiesRuleFile`

Comment: maybe you did not compile the code (auto-build in eclipse might be disabled)? or it was not deployed / not packaged correctly (check file timestamps in tomcat? BTW you can edit your question to improve it instead of adding code in comments.

Comment: Everything is set up correctly. Only this one class is affected.
When he is changing servlets for example everything is working like a charm...
Can that be an eclipse bug?

Comment: eclipse bug is very unlikely. Try deleting everything in your tomcat's temp dir

Comment: Top menu bar --> Go to project --> Check Build Automatically..You are done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure Eclipse actually builds the class file. JSP files are compiled by the web server at runtime, so changes there might work.

Look at the file system, make sure that the time stamps of all the `.class` files change when you save a change in Eclipse.

Comment: This one class was not updated at all...
Time stamp is from 3 days ago.

Comment: so your class was not rebuilt, therefore does not contain the new property value. rebuild the project (project -> clean, project -> build). problem solved.

Comment: Ok then what was the reason for that?

Comment: Two common reasons: 1. "Build automatically" in the "Project" menus is off. 2. You're using Maven and there is this error "Build environment is not up to date" in the error view. That means Eclipse won't build the project at all.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by shared? If you are using some sort of source control application, the problem is most likely there. Quick fix if you are pressed for time would be just copying the entire project directory, and creating a project from said directory. Also, tomcat has a tendency to not 'update' your deployed project for some reason. If, however, you kill the work/catalina folder and re deploy your project it should work.

Comment: Then how is is possible that everything except that class was deployed? Yeah I did export project and then import it to his workspace.

Comment: Its the only class you changed, correct? So how do you know all other classes were compiled and deployed properly? You do not need to compile some content, such as HTML/XML pages, JSP pages, or JavaScript on said pages.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the project from your container, clean the container and redeploy the project